# What do you call the cord that stretches tents that are nailed to the ground?

Tags: word-request

What do you call the cord that stretches tents that are nailed to the ground?

[image]

I am talking about the orange cords we see in the picture above. They seem to be nailed to the ground and seems to be stretching the tents. What do you call those things?

Comment: I'm looking at the image and I don't see any cords.  There are short straps that hold the fly sheet to the ground. The fly sheet is stretched over some oranage poles. But there are no cords.  There are no guy ropes in this image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ropes are **guy lines** or **guy ropes** (both sometimes hyphenated or given as one word), the "nails" in the ground are **tent pegs**.

> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tent): large tents are usually anchored using guy ropes tied to stakes or tent pegs.